# React Native fetch vs XMLHttpRequest performance

Tags: json, performance, react-native, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm trying to figure out why when using axios (which uses XMLHttpRequest), parsing a large (4-5mb json) takes about 10 times more than when using just fetch and .json() on the result. Even worse, when using XMLHttpRequest the whole UI becomes unresponsive, while using fetch there might be a tiny block when doing the json parsing but the UI is responsive pretty much throughout the download process.

I can't find any documentation about the internals of fetch, but outdated blogs say it just uses XMLHttpRequest internally. If this is true, then both methods should have similar performance.

Note: This difference was seen on both Android and IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can find is that the JSON parsing on fetch is done on a lower level than what axios does. With axios it happens later on in the request, but on the react-native package, the parsing of the JSON happens [straight after getting the response](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9a8c06b502c774f7a0bff1bdc064fbfe16ca75be/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js#L253).

The extra layer of returning the data from `XMLHttpRequest` in string form to axios, who then starts parsing the data is most likely the impact on the performance.

The react-native version of [`fetch`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2fe3dd2e7d27789918079c66636c5161e22c5c33/Libraries/Network/fetch.js) is also just a polyfill, so it's not that. It's the way how `fetch` parses the data straight from the `XMLHttpRequest` that is the difference in performance.

Comment: Looks like it. Axios decodes the JSON output on the JS side, while fetch does it on native?

Comment: It looks like the thread fetch does it, is still on a separate thread than the UI thread, which would explain that. The code is hard to follow, but it does point to that.

Answer (score -1):

[From Mozilla API Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> ...an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network.
>   This kind of functionality was previously achieved using XMLHttpRequest. Fetch provides a better alternative that can be easily used by other technologies...

Fetch isn't just a wrapper to XMLHttpRequest. This justifies the performance difference between the two alternatives.

Comment: In react-native `fetch` is being polyfilled by `whatwg-fetch` and uses `XMLHttpRequest` internally. On the web, you are right; it is a different implementation.